# keep separate text on the same line as div tag

Tags: html, css, text

I have am using CSS to sytle part of my text font to bold. But I don't want the whole line to be bold. Just part of the text. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div>
   <div id="titleLabels">Revision:</div> 1.0 draft A
</div>
```

CSS

```
#titleLabels 
{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

The output of this is this:

[image]

This is not what I want. I want the "1.0 draft A bit to be inline with the bit that says Revision".

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why are you using a div if you don't want line breaks?

Comment: @Quentin so that I can make part of the text bold.

Comment: @Dan you can do as posted below or use `<b>` or `<span>` tag.

Comment: @Dan — Use a generic inline container (span) instead of a generic block container (div) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display:inline` to `#titleLabels`:

```css
#titleLabels {
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="titleLabels">Revision:</div>1.0 draft A
</div>
```

Divs by default are block level elements and will take up the full width of their parent element unless you alter that.

A more logical solution would be to not use divs on the revision text and instead use either `<strong>`, `<b>` or a `<span>` with the font-weight styled.

```css
#titleLabels {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>Revision:</b>1.0 draft A
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Revision:</strong>1.0 draft A
</div>
<div>
  <span id="titleLabels">Revision:</span>1.0 draft A
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block`

```css
#titleLabels 
{
   font-weight: bold;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="titleLabels">Revision:</div> 1.0 draft A
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<b>` tag to simply set a certain segment of text as bold

```html
<div>
   <b>Revision:</b> 1.0 draft A
</div>
```